# How to optimize sequential reading and backtracking the position of the file c#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, io, buffer

I have an indefinitely big file. I am to find largest matches of segments of the file with some byte arrays of different lengths.

What I do now is this.

1-Created a `FileStream fs`

```
ForEach byte b in fs.

  save currentPosition.
  //these byte arrays are different depending on b
  ForEach byte array
          while matching bytes 
             read from fs.
          print matched sequence.
          seek to position
```

Now the program is slow. How can I improve my reading from the file?

From what I read, the `fs` has an internal buffer, so when I read a byte, it looks ahead by default 4kb.

My questions:
Am I correct in assuming that the sequential reads of the bytes in fs inside the while loop are satisfied from that buffer?

If so, what happens when I seek back? Does the buffer get destroyed and I read fill it again with the same content for each byte array? Because I need the same buffer, but I just want to reiterate the buffer.

Also, after I have iterated all the byte arrays, and I want to move on to next `b`what happens to that buffer, because what I really want is that same buffer but without the first byte.

How does this work? Do I need to create a wrapper for the FileStream, to read a byte array (that buffer) myself, and satisfy my reads from that buffer?

Edit: From task manager I see that the average of the processor my program uses is 2%. So the fact that the program is slow must be because of the file reads.

Comment: Try to use a [BufferedStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.bufferedstream?view=netframework-4.7.2) to improve performance. If the Seek operations happen within the currently buffered data, this might avoid physical seeks.

Comment: Might? I changed to BufferedStream but I don't see any difference.

Comment: Does it make any difference how it seeks? (Seek origin. FromStart or Current?)

Comment: Have you created it with `new BufferedStream(fs, size)` where size must be substantially bigger than the size of the arrays to compare with (since I guess that you are seeking back by this array size, once you've found a match).

Comment: No, I created without size. I don't know what the default size is (I read about the filestream that was 2k), but I guess it is much larger than the sizes of the arrays (almost all of them are shorter than 5).
In the end, I changed to reading an array of bytes, appending it to a linked list.
And I removed the first element of the list when I was finished with it. 
I achieved O(1) for reading sequentially, appending, and removing first element from it. The performance was much better.